# Reload a div in sidebar of google docs add on using app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a modal dialogue box which gets some input from the user. I store those values in PropertiesService. I want to reload a particular div in the sidebar with the values got from the user(which is stored in PropertiesService) when the form in modal dialogue box is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Intercom library](https://github.com/diy/intercom.js/) to communicate between the dialog and the sidebar.

The open source library intercom.js builds a messaging system on top of the HTML5 LocalStorage API, allowing for dialogs and sidebars in the same browser to communicate with each other.

Check this [sample code](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-dialog2sidebar) by [Eric Koleda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/702875/eric-koleda) on setting up a communication channel between a dialog and a sidebar in Apps Script.